# what is trailing whitespace and how can I handle this?

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I have some code like:

```
        if self.tagname and self.tagname2 in list1:
            try: 
                question = soup.find("div", "post-text")
                title = soup.find("a", "question-hyperlink")
                self.list2.append(str(title)+str(question)+url)
                current += 1
            except AttributeError:
                pass            
        logging.info("%s questions passed, %s questions \
            collected" % (count, current))
        count += 1
    return self.list2
```

My IDE gave me some pep8 warnings, like so:

```
trailing whitespace 37:try
trailing whitespace 43:pass
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: A good explanation of these warnings is given here: https://www.flake8rules.com/
and yours https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W291.html
 (flake8 is an inspection tool)

Comment: White spaces do not affect your coding function, but removing them definitely makes your code much cleaner and avoids unwanted small mistakes. If you use VS Code, you can put this into your `settings.json` file to automatically trim all the white spaces whenever you save a file.
```
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
```

Comment: I don't understand how the question could be asked. It seems to be a question about English, not a question about programming. "Trailing whitespace" is simply [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) which follows ([trails](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trailing)) the line of code.

Answer (score 55):

Trailing whitespace is any spaces or tabs after the last non-whitespace character on the line until the newline.

In your posted question, there is one extra space after `try:`, and there are 12 extra spaces after `pass`:

```
>>> post_text = '''\
...             if self.tagname and self.tagname2 in list1:
...                 try: 
...                     question = soup.find("div", "post-text")
...                     title = soup.find("a", "question-hyperlink")
...                     self.list2.append(str(title)+str(question)+url)
...                     current += 1
...                 except AttributeError:
...                     pass            
...             logging.info("%s questions passed, %s questions \
...                 collected" % (count, current))
...             count += 1
...         return self.list2
... '''
>>> for line in post_text.splitlines():
...     if line.rstrip() != line:
...         print(repr(line))
... 
'                try: '
'                    pass            '
```

See where the strings end? There are spaces before the lines (indentation), but also spaces after.

Use your editor to find the end of the line and backspace. Many modern text editors can also automatically remove trailing whitespace from the end of the line, for example every time you save a file.

Comment: In emacs: `C-M-% <space> + $` then press return twice. Wow, that looks more cryptic than it feels when I type it.

Comment: surely trailing whitespace is valid (and reported by PEP8) on every line, not only after `:`, right?

Comment: @Christoph: sorry, yes, all trailing whitespace; that was an editing error.

Answer (score 31):

Trailing whitespace:

```
It is extra spaces (and tabs) at the end of line      
                                                 ^^^^^ here
```

Strip them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
"""\
strip trailing whitespace from file
usage: stripspace.py <file>
"""

import sys

if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 1:
  sys.exit(__doc__)

content = ''
outsize = 0
inp = outp = sys.argv[1]
with open(inp, 'rb') as infile:
  content = infile.read()
with open(outp, 'wb') as output:
  for line in content.splitlines():
    newline = line.rstrip(" \t")
    outsize += len(newline) + 1
    output.write(newline + '\n')

print("Done. Stripped %s bytes." % (len(content)-outsize))
```

https://gist.github.com/techtonik/c86f0ea6a86ed3f38893

Answer (score 14):

This is just a warning and it doesn't make problem for your project to run, you can just ignore it and continue coding.
But if you're obsessed about clean coding, same as me, you have two options:

1. Hover the mouse on warning in VS Code or any IDE and use quick fix to remove white spaces.
2. Press `f1` then type `trim trailing whitespace`.

Answer (score 8):

I have got similar pep8 warning `W291 trailing whitespace`

```
long_text = '''Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text  <-remove whitespace
of the printing and typesetting industry.'''
```

Try to explore trailing whitespaces and remove them. ex: two whitespaces at the end of `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text`

Comment: Works to me! I just change `"""` to `'''`