# Make category words appear separately on ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF taxinomy sub field. I am searching for a way to display multiple categorys from this field. The code I am using display all categories but the word touch each other, and don't separate.
How to make those category words appear separately ?

```
                        <?php
                        $term = get_sub_field('categories'); 
                            if( $term ) {
                              foreach($term as $t) {
                                $t = get_category($t);
                                echo $t->name;
                              }
                            }
                            ?>
```

[image: see the category in gray on this picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) a space to your category names. You can achieve this in multiple ways.

The simplest way would be:

```
<?php
$term = get_sub_field('categories');
if ($term) {
    foreach ($term as $t) {
        $t = get_category($t);
        echo $t->name . ' ';
    }
}
```

> This way concatenates a space `' '` **after** each element. So your string will end up with a final space (also called [trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21410075/1534704)). This may be an issue or maybe not.

Another way:

```
<?php
$term = get_sub_field('categories');
if ($term) {
    $first = true;
    foreach ($term as $t) {
        $t = get_category($t);
        echo ($first ? '' : ' ') . $t->name;
        $first = false;
    }
}
```

> This time we use a boolean `$first` variable and the ternary operator [Shorthand If/Else](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) to concatenate the space **before** each element except the first one. This way your HTML code gets a clean string (without trailing spaces).

Even another way to get a clean string would be:

```
<?php
$term = get_sub_field('categories');
if ($term) {
    $cats = [];
    foreach ($term as $t) {
        $t = get_category($t);
        $cats[] = $t->name;
    }
    echo implode(' ', $cats);
}
```

> In this example we [`push`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) all category names to `$cats` array to finally convert (and `echo`) this array to string with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

I hope this helps you to understand it! :)

Comment: This is actually really clear. It fix my problem. Thank you.